# What happens when the maximum number of WCF connections is reached?

Tags: .net, wcf, concurrency

We have a service (A) which Calls another WCF service (B).

Service B has the default values of

```
<serviceThrottling 
      maxConcurrentCalls="16"
      maxConcurrentSessions="10" 
      maxConcurrentInstances="26" />
```

Service A can spawn up to 150 threads, which some of them can call service B.

what happens if service A calls service B with more than the max amount of concurrent connections?

Does service B (WCF) throws them away or stores them in a queue?

Comment: The extra calls will wait for the defined timeout period, and if no service instance becomes available to service them within that time, they'll fail (most likely with a `TimeoutException`).

Comment: @marc_s - I'm curious to know why you put that information in a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client is blocked until a connection becomes available.

Of course, this behavior indicates the existence of another queue, holding waiting connection requests. I assume that queue would have its own threshold, so once there are a maximum number of waiting connections, further incoming requests would be thrown away. (This is just conjecture on my part, I don't know where this theoretical queue is configured. .....Somebody?).

I actually experienced a problem in my automated tests where connections were not getting dropped, and this ultimately resulted in my system hanging because the threshold was reached.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031284/25216

Comment: Andrew, Your answer was really good, thanks. I got back to it because I want to know how I can limit this queue, Did you find out anything or maybe you can point me in a direction? you think it may have anything to do with the tcp backlog, maybe?